# Metrics for multiclass classification

Tags: classification, clustering, multinomial-distribution, unsupervised-learning, multi-class

### **Background**

Consider a clustering problem where a dataset of measurements $Z\triangleq\{z_i\}_{i=1}^m$ must be partioned in $n$ clusters, where $n$ is unknown and must be estimated.
Here the term "partition" has the following specific meaning:

1. a partition $P$ is a finite set of $n$ clusters $C_1,\dots,C_{n}$: $P\triangleq\{C_i\}_{i=1}^n$;
2. each cluster $C_i\in P$ is a subset of the dataset: $C_i\subseteq Z$;
3. two different clusters $C_i$, $C_j \in P$ does not overlap with each other: $C_i \cap C_j=\varnothing$ when $i\neq j$
4. the union of all clusters in the partition gives back the starting dataset: $\cup_{i=1}^nC_i =Z$.

There are several algorithms able to solve this problem, i.e. to generate a resonable partion $P$. For example, a popular choice is [DBSCAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBSCAN).

In some sense, the current problem is a multiclass classification problem, where one want to assign a label $\ell\in\{1,2,\dots,\eta\}$, which in turn identifies a cluster in the partition, to each measurement $z_i$ in the dataset.

---

### **Problem**

Let say that we want find a good tuning for the DBSCAN parameters $\theta$. In order to do that, we need two ingredients:

1. the true partition $P$, which is composed by $n$ clusters, of the dataset $Z$. Actually $P$ is known because the dataset $Z$ and the relative measurements labels $\ell_1,\dots,\ell_m$ are generated by a sensor simulator that is under my control.
2. a metric $d:\mathcal{P}(Z)\times \mathcal{P}(Z)\mapsto \mathbb{R}^{+}$ over the space $\mathcal{P}(Z)$ of each possible partitions of the dataset $Z$

Now, lets say that DBSCAN generates the partition $\hat{P}_1$ when the parameters are $\theta_1$ and generates the partition $\hat{P}_2$ when the parameters are $\theta_2$. Then, we can say that the setting $\theta_1$ is better than the setting $\theta_2$ iff
\begin{equation*}d\left(\hat{P}_1, P\right)< d\left(\hat{P}_2,P\right)\end{equation*}

The problem is: how do we define a resonable metric $d(\cdot,\cdot)$ in the current problem?

---

### **Idea to solve the problem**

I think that the most intuitive way to tackle the problem is to adapt to the current circumstances the ideas behind the [confusion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix). In particular, once it is clarified what is the intended confusion matrix, a solving strategy can be the following:

- **step 1**: given $\hat{P}$ and $P$, compute the confusion matrix $M\left(\hat{P},P\right)$
- **step 2**: given the confusion matrix $M\left(\hat{P},P\right)$, define the classification score $d(\cdot,\cdot)$ as (for example) the classification accuracy, i.e. the fraction of the number $\sum_{i=1}^n M_{ii}$ of measurements correctly classified over the total number $m$ of measurements
  \begin{equation*}
  d\left(\hat{P},P\right)\triangleq 100\,\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n M_{ii}\left(\hat{P},P\right)}{m}
   \,\%\end{equation*}
  here $M_{ij}$ denotes the $ij$-th entry of the confusion matrix.

---

### **Issues**

The definition of the confusion matrix is not trivial because of two typical issues of the current classification problem.

- **issue #1**: the number of classes / clusters $\hat{n}$ estimated by DBSCAN can be different from the real one $n$
- **issue #2**: even if DBSCAN generates the true partition, the accuracy can be smaller than 100% because the label convention used by DBSCAN can be different by the one used to encode the true partition. The best way to explain this concept is to provide a toy example.

**example 1**

Let's consider a dataset of $m\triangleq 4$ measuremenst and assume that the true partition is encoded as follows
\begin{equation*}
\begin{array}{ c| c c c c}
 P & z_1 & z_2 & z_3 & z_4\\ 
\hline
 \ell(z) & 1 & 1 & 2 & 3\\  
\end{array}
\end{equation*}
now let's assume that DBSCAN generates the following result
\begin{equation*}
\begin{array}{ c| c c c c}
 \hat{P} & z_1 & z_2 & z_3 & z_4\\ 
\hline
 \hat{\ell}(z) & 2 & 2 & 1 & 3\\  
\end{array}
\end{equation*}

despite DBSCAN use a different terminology to denote the clusters, the partion is correct because, as it should be,

- $z_1,z_2$ belong to the same cluster. Here the true label is "$1$", but DBSCAN uses "$2$".
- $z_3$ defines a singleton. Here the true label is "$2$", but DBSCAN uses "$1$".
- $z_4$ defines a singleton. Here the true label is "$3$" and DBSCAN uses "$3$" as well.

and so in this case the accuracy should be 100%.  However, if one employs the "naive" definition of the confusion matrix then it turns out a smaller value. Indeed, let's define "naively" the confusion matrix via the following rule:

> the entry $M_{ij}$ counts the number of times that the true cluster $C_i$ contains a measurement in the estimated cluster $\hat{C}_j$

accordingly, the confusion matrix gets the following value
\begin{equation*}
M\left(\hat{P},P\right)= \left[\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 2 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right] \qquad
\leftrightarrow
\qquad
\begin{array}{ c c|  c c c}
 & \hat{\ell}(z) & 1 & 2 & 3\\ 
 \ell(z) & &  &  & \\ 
\hline
 1 & & 0 & 2 & 0\\  
 2 & & 1 & 0 & 0\\  
 3 & & 0 & 0 & 1\\  
\end{array}
\end{equation*}
and so, it turns out that the accuracy is just
\begin{equation*}
d\left(\hat{P},P\right)=100\,\frac{0+0+1}{4}\,\% = 25\%
\end{equation*}

In conclusion, the intuition says that the accuracy is 100%, my procedure says that it is 25%.

---

### **Issue #1**

The proposed solving strategy seems to almost directly apply also in the case where the estimated number $\hat{n}$ of clusters is not equal to the real one $n$. The difference is in the shape of the confusion matrix, which now is no more always square but rather has dimension $n\times \hat{n}$. Moreover, due to the generic rectangular shape, some diagonal entries don't exist and so, in order to take account of this fact, the accuracy has to be generalized as follows
\begin{equation*}
d\left(\hat{P},P\right)\triangleq 100\,\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{\min(\hat{n},n)} M_{ii}\left(\hat{P},P\right)}{m}\,\%
\end{equation*}
fortunately this is the only required modification to the previous basic scheme.
Naturally the "terminology problem" (issue #2) still persists, and in this more general context there more "strange dynamics" in which one has to deal for.

**example 2**

Let's consider the same true partition of example 1 and let's consider the following output from DBSCAN

\begin{equation*}
\begin{array}{ c| c c c c}
 \hat{P} & z_1 & z_2 & z_3 & z_4\\ 
\hline
 \hat{\ell}(z) & 1 & 1 & 1 & 2\\  
\end{array}
\end{equation*}

clearly, the partition is not correct because of the mismatch between $n\triangleq 3$ and $\hat{n}\triangleq 2$. Once again, the "terminology problem" causes an underevaluation of the accuracy, indeed

- $z_1, z_2$, as it should be, belongs to the same cluster. Here DBSCAN uses the correct label
- $z_3$, as it shouldn't be, belongs to the $z_1,z_2$ cluster. Here DBSCAN generates an error that is not caused by a wrong use of the label name, but is truly caused by the incapacity of DBSCAN to recognise the similarity that $z_3$ has with respect to $z_1,z_2$. In this sense, this is a "true error".
- $z_4$, as it should be, defines a singleton. Here DBSCAN uses the wrong label, and so it generates a "false error" (i.e. merely caused by the wrong terminology).

the accuracy in this case should be 75% because only $z_3$ is wrongly classified. On the other hand the naive version of my procedure gives the confusion matrix
\begin{equation*}
M\left(\hat{P},P\right)= \left[\begin{array}{cc}
2 & 0 \\
1 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{array}\right] \qquad
\leftrightarrow
\qquad
\begin{array}{ c c|  c c }
 & \hat{\ell}(z) & 1 & 2 \\ 
 \ell(z) & &  &  & \\ 
\hline
 1 & & 2 & 0\\  
 2 & & 1 & 0\\  
 3 & & 0 & 1\\  
\end{array}
\end{equation*}
from which follows the accuracy
\begin{equation*}
d\left(\hat{P},P\right)=100\,\frac{2+0}{4}\,\%=50\%
\end{equation*}

In conclusion, the intuition says that the accuracy is 75%, while the procedure says 50%.

**example 3**

With the same true partition, consider the following output

\begin{equation*}
\begin{array}{ c| c c c c}
 \hat{P} & z_1 & z_2 & z_3 & z_4\\ 
\hline
 \hat{\ell}(z) & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\  
\end{array}
\end{equation*}

now the cardinality mismatch is $n\triangleq 3$ versus $\hat{n}\triangleq 4$ and holds the following

- $z_1$ defines a singleton with correct label.
- $z_2$ defines, wrongly, a singleton. Actually, $z_2$ should be linked with $z_1$ and so here DBSCAN commits a "true error"
- $z_3$ defines a singleton, but DBSCAN commits a "false error" due to the wrong label name
- $z_4$ defines a singleton, but DBSCAN commits another "false error"

hence, the accuracy should be 75% because of $z_2$. The confusion matrix is

\begin{equation*}
M\left(\hat{P},P\right)= \left[\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right] \qquad
\leftrightarrow
\qquad
\begin{array}{ c c|  c c c c}
 & \hat{\ell}(z) & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\ 
 \ell(z) &  &  &  & & \\ 
\hline
 1 & & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\  
 2 & & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\  
 3 & & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\  
\end{array}
\end{equation*}
from which follows the accuracy
\begin{equation*}
d\left(\hat{P},P\right)=100\,\frac{1+0+0}{4}\,\%=25\%
\end{equation*}

The intuition says that the accuracy is 75%, while the procedure says 25%.

---

### **Conclusions**

Summarizing, my proposed metric seems to work even when the number of estimated class does not coincide with the true one. On the other hand, suffers from the "terminology problem", which casuses the introduction of "false errors" that leads to an underestimation of the accuracy (defined by the intuition).

The false errors can be removed by employing a re-labeling operation, in which one tries to match terminology used by DBSCAN and the true partition. For example:

- in example 1, swapping the names of $\hat{C}_{1}$ and $\hat{C}_2$ solves the false errors
- in example 2, changing the name of $\hat{C}_2$ in $\hat{C}_3$ solve the false error
- in example 3, changing the name of $\hat{C}_3$ in $\hat{C}_2$ and changing the name of $\hat{C_4}$ in $\hat{C}_3$ solves the false errors.

Then, my proposed procedure with the "false error" correction seems to provide a good metric to evaluate the performance of a clustering algorithm.

---

### Questions

At the end of the day, I have two questions.

- **question #1**: I don't know how to formalize (and, consequently, to solve) the "re-labeling" procedure, hence my question is - *how do we solve the re-labeling problem in a such way that everything ends up in an algorithm that can be automatically computed by a computer?*
- **question #2**: The problem to define a clustering metric is nothing new. I would like to have a perspective of someone more expert than me about this topic. My question is the following - *is there a clustering metric that takes into account the eventuality that the number of classes does not coincide with the estimated number of classes?*

Comment: For some reason, clustering distance measures are called "indices" in the literature. A search for "clustering external indices" should yield plenty of resources.

Comment: You could score them as follows: for each pair of points (or a sample of the pairs if $m$ is huge) $z_i, z_j$, check if your partition puts them in the same cluster. If you get it right then you get a point. The inverse of the number of points (minus the inverse of the maximum possible score) could be a useful metric

Comment: For those are interested, I've found a possible approach to the "re-labeling" problem.
I'm discussing the idea here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4714383/optimization-problem-over-matrices

Comment: See e.g. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/24961/comparing-clusterings-rand-index-vs-variation-of-information for a discussion of well-established and well-tested metric distances between clusterings. I would go with one of those.

Comment: Thank you micans, I'll read carefully your resource. BTW I've solved my problem, and it seems that my solution is the so-called Maximum Match Measure. You can find the details starting from here
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4716336/optimization-problem-over-matrices-part-3/4717575#4717575