# Is 0.53 good score for Rand Index?

Tags: clustering

my prof told me to use rand index between two clustering on my assignment, and after using python sckitlearn library i got the score 0.53

is it good score? i can't find any reference about it like i found Silhouette Coefficient

Answer (score 1):

As with *all* the other metrics like this, the number is rather meaningless alone. The [meaning is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rand_index)

> The Rand index has a value between 0 and 1, with 0 indicating that the two data clusterings do not agree on any pair of points and 1 indicating that the data clusterings are exactly the same.

If it's anything in between 0 and 1 you must compare it to say that the similarity between two clusterings is higher or lower than between others.

Comment: i see. guess that make sense 
thank you

Comment: @bintang if that answers your question, you can accept the answer to mark it as "solved".

Answer (score 1):

[Elsewhere](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/24961/comparing-clusterings-rand-index-vs-variation-of-information) I've written a long answer explaining why I think the Rand index is not a good choice when comparing two clusterings. The short summary is that by counting pairs of points the size of the clusters have a very distorting effect. An additional point is that the Rand index tells you nothing about any subsumption (subset) relationship between the two clusterings (this is the case for any comparison that returns a single value).

Going a little bit beyond your question, I'd like to mention that it is possible to glean more information from your data, even when using the Rand index. Call your clusterings `A` and `B`. Consider the greatest common subclustering of A and B, call it `C`. The complement of the Rand index `r` (one minus r: `1-r`) is sometimes called the (scaled) Mirkin distance. Rand is a similarity: 0 is maximally different, 1 is identical. Mirkin is a distance: 0 is identical, 1 is maximally distant. In your case you have `Rand(A,B) = 0.53`, so that `Mirkin(A,B) = 0.47`.

It is informative to calculate `Mirkin(A,C)` and `Mirkin(B,C)`, noting that `Mirkin(A,B) = Mirkin(A,C) + Mirkin(B,C)`. If one of those numbers is much smaller than the other, it indicates that the one with the smaller number is approximately or to some extent a subclustering of the other.