# Comparing partitions with different number of clusters

Tags: clustering

Say that we have a ground-truth partiton $U$ consisting of $k$ clusters and two partitions $V_1$ and $V_2$ obtained via two different algorithms :

- $V_1$ consists of $k$ clusters.
- $V_2$ was obtained through an apporach that does not need an à priori number of cluster. Say it consists of $g$ clusters.

When computing metrics such as ARI, NMI, and AMI on the pairs ($U$,$V_1$) and ($U$,$V_2$), does $V_2$ have an advantage over $V_1$ due to $g>k$ or $g<k$. Is it fair to compare the metrics obtained from the two partitions or do the partitions have to have the same number of clusters for it to be fair?

Answer (score 0):

This ties in to another phenomenon that is sometimes overlooked; namely to what extent there is a subclustering relationship between any of the pairs of clusterings. My answer is that it is not fair, with three aspects highlighted. First, it pays to quantify **the extent of subclustering**. Luckily this can be done with existing indices on clustering, where my preference by far is to use metric distances between clusterings rather than say the adjusted Rand index. The space of all clusterings (aka partitions) of a set are a very neat mathematical object. They form a lattice under the subclustering relationship. I see no reason to introduce a 'chance' element (such as the adjusted Rand index does) when **the rigor and simplicity of a metric distance** is available (the second aspect). Examples are the Mirkin distance, the Variation of Information distance and the Split/Join distance. I've extensively described these three [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/24961/comparing-clusterings-rand-index-vs-variation-of-information), noting that especially Mirkin is **heavily affected by cluster sizes** and thus may give very distorted results (the third aspect).
For each of these, the distance *d(x,y)* between two clusterings *x* and *y* can be deconstructed as *d(x,y)* = d(x, GCS(x,y)) + d(y, GCS(x,y))* where *GCS(x,y)* denotes the *Greatest Common Subclustering* of *x* and *y*. Splitting it into these two contributions allows to assess the amount of subclustering of one versus the other, if present. Hence, I always recommend that distances between clusterings are expressed in such pairs - as in [this recent answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/618304/is-0-53-good-score-for-rand-index).

In [this preprint](https://www.biorxiv.org/content/10.1101/2022.10.09.511493v1) in Section 8 I use this technique to inspect and visualise ensembles of clusterings made by Leiden and MCL in a heat map.